# Eigen vector corresponding to eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the eigen vector of the matrix $(0,1;-2,-3)$
When I find and put the the eigen value to find the eigen vector ; I find  $y=-2x$

When I give $x=1$, $y = -2$, but if I give $x=-1$ , I find $y=2$
Which one is eigent vector $v(1,-2)$ or $v(-1,2)$

I hope I could explain what i want to ask.

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique - you can use either.

Comment: Typically in linear algebra, if there is no word problem (aka "application") associated with such a problem, it is customary to find an eigen vector that has entries relative prime with respect to each other. So any of your answers would work.

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=0kSNQtLOaZM but if i solve this system accourding to different eigen vector, the result is diffrent from the one I solved..

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are eigenvectors, because multiplying eigenvector with constant leaves it eigen: $A v = \lambda v$, and for $w = \mu \cdot v$ and non-zero constant $\mu$ we have $Aw = A(\mu \cdot v) = \mu \cdot Av = \mu \cdot \lambda v = \lambda \cdot(\mu \cdot v) = \lambda w$, so $w$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=0kSNQtLOaZM but if i solve this system accourding to different eigen vector, the result is diffrent from the one I solved..

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -2 & -3\end{pmatrix}$ has to different eigenvalues and for each there is an one-dimensional space of eigenvectors. So, $v _1= (-1, 2)$ corresponds to one of them and $v_2 = (-1, 1)$ to another.

Comment: can we say v1=(-1/2,1) and (-1,1) are eigen vector as well ?

Comment: Yes, they are eigenvectors as well as their multipliers.